# Review count currently in wrong location on Review page on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, user-interface

I just went to the Review pages, and no matter which queue I'm in ("Close Votes", "Suggested Edits", etc.), my overall review count is now located below the "progress" bar that indicates badge progress.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but wasn't this number to the left of the badge progress bar before?

It's below the line dividing the header, which includes the title "Close Votes" plus the badge progress bar, and stats, history, and the review tabs, yet it's above the box that asks the review question, e.g. "Should this question be closed as **not a real question**?".

This occurs on my Windows 7 PC, in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Was this misplacement of the review count intentional or a bug?  Either way, to me it looks strange.

[image: Overall Count Misplaced]

Comment: Same in Safari for me.

Comment: Who broke it this time?  Repro on Chrome Mac

Comment: I noticed it on iPad 2 too.

Comment: Reproed in Mac Chrome.

Comment: It certainly doesn't look intentional.

Comment: Repro on Chrome latest for Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fixed now and it will be out in the next deployment.

[image: fix]

Comment: The count is back in place.  Thanks.