# Badge 'progress bar' style changes

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, review, user-interface

Just noticed a light grey *(#ececec)* border to the badge progress bars on SO in the review queues.

Looks (odd|fuzzy|blurred) on a white background and, well, rather 1990's on a dark background. presumably the progress count (1,292 in my case) is trying to distance itself from the change.

Is this intentional?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I've mentioned the odd location of the review count [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185698/review-count-currently-in-wrong-location-on-review-page-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: @rgettman Indeed (+1)

Comment: I fail to see how this question is a dupe - It only requires reading the title to gauge the primary question.

Comment: @nichkhar I didn't say it was a duplicate, but it certainly is related.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @rgettman Apologies - It appears that MSO statuses have changed in nature. I noticed the word "may"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's now fixed and will be out in the next deployment.

[image: fix]

Comment: ~28mins to fix. Tomorrow obviously seemed too long to wait. Nice! :)

Comment: @nickhar technically I did fix it the next day...